# How to tell the difference between scp and ssh in .bash_profile

Tags: ssh, sudo, scp

I have the following line embedded in `.bash_profile` for a remote server:

```
export JMXPASS=`sudo /bin/cat /opt/jmxr.pass`
```

When I ssh to the remote server, I get prompted for my password (expected behavior). However, when I scp from or to this remote server, I get the following error

```
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

I want to insert an if condition inside .bash_profile that has the effect of:

```
if [ssh'ing] then 
    export JMXPASS=`sudo /bin/cat /opt/jmxr.pass`
fi;
```

Can someone tell me what needs to be the condition check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common condition used in the beginning of `~/.bashrc` is

```
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac
```

It will `return` if the bash is not interactive (`scp` case) and run further in the other cases.

Comment: Thanks @Jakuje. As per your suggestion, I took a look at /etc/.bashrc and /etc/.bash_profile and found `if shopt -q login_shell ; then # We're in a login shell`. I don't know what this if condition is doing but it's working for me. Thanks again.